# Resize only a part of texture, OpenGL

Tags: user-interface, opengl, graphics, 2d, textures

I'm working on GUI in OpenGL. I'm using this image to texture my button:
[image]

You can't see it very well, but it has a light border (2 pixels width) around it.

What I want to achieve is to have nicely resizable button which keeps it's borders untouched. According to hints given me here, on StackOverflow I decided to use 9-cell-pattern, so I divided my quad into 9 parts like this:

[image]

I really like an effect I achieved if it goes about borders, but the problem is with a quad that is in the center (9th):

[image]

I would like to repeat or wrap a texture like I do but with ignoring borders.

So my question is - is there any way to do this with only one texture which I'm using now? Or should I create second texture, which would be decreased by a border width and to render this quad in the middle with this texture?

Also I don't know if it's necessary, but I'm putting here a fragment of my code:

This is a code I'm using for tiling/wrapping a texture:

```
switch(m_bTiling)
{
case true:
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
                     GL_REPEAT );
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
                     GL_REPEAT );
    break;
case false:
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
                     GL_CLAMP );
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
                     GL_CLAMP );
    break;
}
```

And here is a code to draw quads:

```
// Top left quad [1]
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    // Bottom left
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0-maxTexCoordBorderY);                     
    glVertex2i(pos.x, pos.y + m_borderWidth);

    // Top left
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0);    
    glVertex2i(pos.x, pos.y);

    // Top right
    glTexCoord2f(maxTexCoordBorderX, 1.0);  
    glVertex2i(pos.x + m_borderWidth, pos.y);

    // Bottom right
    glTexCoord2f(maxTexCoordBorderX, 1.0-maxTexCoordBorderY);
    glVertex2i(pos.x + m_borderWidth, pos.y + m_borderWidth);
glEnd();

// Top middle quad [2]
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    // Bottom left
    glTexCoord2f(maxTexCoordBorderX, 1.0 - maxTexCoordBorderY);             
    glVertex2i(pos.x + m_borderWidth, pos.y + m_borderWidth);

    // Top left
    glTexCoord2f(maxTexCoordBorderX, 1.0);
    glVertex2i(pos.x + m_borderWidth, pos.y);

    // Top right
    glTexCoord2f(maxTexCoordWidth - maxTexCoordBorderX, 1.0);   
    glVertex2i(pos.x + width - m_borderWidth, pos.y);

    // Bottom right
    glTexCoord2f(maxTexCoordWidth - maxTexCoordBorderX, 1.0 - maxTexCoordBorderY);
    glVertex2i(pos.x + width - m_borderWidth, pos.y + m_borderWidth);
glEnd();

// Top right quad [3]
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    // Bottom left
    glTexCoord2f(1.0 - maxTexCoordBorderX, 1.0 - maxTexCoordBorderY);                   
    glVertex2i(pos.x + width - m_borderWidth, pos.y + m_borderWidth);

    // Top left
    glTexCoord2f(1.0 - maxTexCoordBorderX, 1.0);
    glVertex2i(pos.x + width - m_borderWidth, pos.y);

    // Top right
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0); 
    glVertex2i(pos.x + width, pos.y);

    // Bottom right
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0 - maxTexCoordBorderY);    
    glVertex2i(pos.x + width, pos.y + m_borderWidth);
glEnd();

// Middle left quad [4]
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    // Bottom left
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, maxTexCoordBorderY);              
    glVertex2i(pos.x, pos.y + height - m_borderWidth);

    // Top left
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, maxTexCoordHeight - maxTexCoordBorderY);
    glVertex2i(pos.x, pos.y + m_borderWidth);

    // Top right
    glTexCoord2f(maxTexCoordBorderX, maxTexCoordHeight - maxTexCoordBorderY);           
    glVertex2i(pos.x + m_borderWidth, pos.y + m_borderWidth);

    // Bottom right
    glTexCoord2f(maxTexCoordBorderX, maxTexCoordBorderY);
    glVertex2i(pos.x + m_borderWidth, pos.y + height - m_borderWidth);
glEnd();

// Middle right quad [5] 
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    // Bottom left
    glTexCoord2f(1.0 - maxTexCoordBorderX, maxTexCoordBorderY);                     
    glVertex2i(pos.x + width - m_borderWidth, pos.y + height - m_borderWidth);

    // Top left
    glTexCoord2f(1.0 - maxTexCoordBorderX, maxTexCoordHeight - maxTexCoordBorderY);
    glVertex2i(pos.x + width - m_borderWidth, pos.y + m_borderWidth);

    // Top right
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, maxTexCoordHeight - maxTexCoordBorderY);  
    glVertex2i(pos.x + width, pos.y + m_borderWidth);

    // Bottom right 
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, maxTexCoordBorderY);  
    glVertex2i(pos.x + width, pos.y + height - m_borderWidth);
glEnd();

// Bottom left quad [6]
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    // Bottom left
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);                     
    glVertex2i(pos.x, pos.y + height);

    // Top left
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, maxTexCoordBorderY);  
    glVertex2i(pos.x, pos.y + height - m_borderWidth);

    // Top right
    glTexCoord2f(maxTexCoordBorderX, maxTexCoordBorderY);   
    glVertex2i(pos.x + m_borderWidth, pos.y + height - m_borderWidth);

    // Bottom right
    glTexCoord2f(maxTexCoordBorderX, 0.0);  
    glVertex2i(pos.x + m_borderWidth, pos.y + height);
glEnd();

// Bottom middle quad [7]
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    // Bottom left
    glTexCoord2f(maxTexCoordBorderX, 0.0);                          
    glVertex2i(pos.x + m_borderWidth, pos.y + height);

    // Top left
    glTexCoord2f(maxTexCoordBorderX, maxTexCoordBorderY);
    glVertex2i(pos.x + m_borderWidth, pos.y + height - m_borderWidth);

    // Top right
    glTexCoord2f(maxTexCoordWidth - maxTexCoordBorderX, maxTexCoordBorderY);    
    glVertex2i(pos.x + width - m_borderWidth, pos.y + height - m_borderWidth);

    // Bottom right
    glTexCoord2f(maxTexCoordWidth - maxTexCoordBorderX, 0.0);   
    glVertex2i(pos.x + width - m_borderWidth, pos.y + height);
glEnd();

// Bottom right quad [8]
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    // Bottom left
    glTexCoord2f(1.0 - maxTexCoordBorderX, 0.0);                        
    glVertex2i(pos.x + width - m_borderWidth, pos.y + height);

    // Top left
    glTexCoord2f(1.0 - maxTexCoordBorderX, maxTexCoordBorderY);
    glVertex2i(pos.x + width - m_borderWidth, pos.y + height - m_borderWidth);

    // Top right
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, maxTexCoordBorderY);  
    glVertex2i(pos.x + width, pos.y + height - m_borderWidth);

    // Bottom right 
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex2i(pos.x + width, pos.y + height);
glEnd();

// Middle middle quad [9]
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    // Bottom left
    glTexCoord2f(maxTexCoordBorderX, maxTexCoordBorderY);                   
    glVertex2i(pos.x + m_borderWidth, pos.y + height - m_borderWidth);

    // Top left
    glTexCoord2f(maxTexCoordBorderX, maxTexCoordHeight - maxTexCoordBorderY);   
    glVertex2i(pos.x + m_borderWidth, pos.y + m_borderWidth);

    // Top right
    glTexCoord2f(maxTexCoordWidth - maxTexCoordBorderX, maxTexCoordHeight - maxTexCoordBorderY);        
    glVertex2i(pos.x + width - m_borderWidth, pos.y + m_borderWidth);

    // Bottom right 
    glTexCoord2f(maxTexCoordWidth - maxTexCoordBorderX, maxTexCoordBorderY);
    glVertex2i(pos.x + width - m_borderWidth, pos.y + height - m_borderWidth);
glEnd();
```

Comment: Notice, that your texture isn't easily tileable because of the color gradient inside. You could try to take a quad from approximate (x=2,y=20,w=18,h=18) and tile it for better results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were stretching the edges/center, you'd be fine, but since you're tiling, you're going to have to create a second texture with just the center part.

Note that this can be done programmatically if you have the size of the border. You'd copy the contents of the center into a new 2d array then upload that to another texture.

Another solution (as I stated in a comment) would be to set the texture coordinates of the middle middle quad to the same ones as the inner vertices of the corner. That way the texture of the center quad is stretched out. Note that this will create some weird stretching on the shine in the top right corner unless the entire thing is contained in the top right corner quad. You'd still have issues with this if you wanted to use your repeat solution.

If you still want to repeat the center part and don't mind moving your entire rendering pipeline to non-deprecated OpenGL, then ananthonline's answer is better. If you don't want to/can't move your rendering code to more modern OpenGL, then the texture copy is pretty much the only solution.

Comment: Thanks Robert for the answer, but what did you mean by stretching the edges/center? Did you mean using GL_CLAMP instead of GL_REPEAT?

Comment: Not specifically, you would just define the texture coordinates of the center quad as the same texture coords of the inside of the corner blocks. That way the center of the texture stretches out over the center quad.

Comment: Duplicating the texture is wasteful, recomputing the texture coords is easier - note that this can also be done much more efficiently using two fragment shaders operating on the same texture with two samplers, see my answer above.

Comment: He's using immediate mode, he might be wanting to target legacy hardware as well. AFAIK there's no way to do this on the fixed-function pipeline other than duplicating a tiny texture. I'll move my solution of stretching the center quad into my answer.

Comment: @RobertRouhani In fact I wasn't even aware of this modern OpenGL, so I didn't consider this solution... you both really helped me, but if you could also answer the comment I wrote below Ananthonline's answer, I'd be glad!

Comment: There's a lot more boilerplate code you have to write. With immediate mode it's multiple methods per vertex, in modern OpenGL, your vertex data is stored in one big array and stored on the GPU, called a Buffer Object. When you create the Buffer Object, you get a handle to it and use it to bind that array as the array of vertices that are going to be drawn.

Comment: On top of that, you also have shaders. These are relatively small bits of a C-like language called GLSL that you write to tell the GPU how to transform your vertices into screen space and how to color each pixel inside a triangle. The other answer suggests that you should write one of these shaders to calculate the offsets for what you would consider repeating instead of what OpenGL considers repeating.

Comment: If you do want to learn about modern OpenGL, I'd recommend this tutorial for it: http://open.gl/

Answer (score 1):

Well - I see your problem. You're using a constant value of maxTexCoordBorderX (and Y) for your "middle middle" quad. You need to recompute the UV coords of the center quads as the size changes (ex: width / (currWidth - 2 * borderWidth)), then you can set that texture to repeat always, but since you modify the texture coords as the  ui element resizes, the center part won't ever repeat.

Of course - if you're going to use a VBO or something more performant at some point of time in the future, you can simply define two fragment shaders (each with their own [sampler2D](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_%28GLSL%29) objects; one repeats, the other stretches) for each of the tiling modes and render all corner quads and middle-middle quads using the "repeat" shader and all edge quads using the stretch shader. This will not require a recompute and ought to be very fast.

Note: You're drawing multiple quads here, this is not a good idea. I would recommend using an indexed mesh with shared vertices. This will minimize the possibility of "tears" at the borders of your quads.

Comment: Thank you Ananthonline for the answer. I have one more question though - I have completely no idea about this modern OpenGL yet so I'll have to read about thos VBOs and rest, but is it possible to just replace this code of drawing quads with 'modern' one or I would have to change all the settings, etc? Also is it much harder than this older version?

Comment: You could do a simple replace - instead of two shaders, use one shader with a uniform controlling what sampler to use (repeat or stretch) and set it appropriately before drawing each quad. The problem with using two shaders in immediate mode drawing is that you'll make that change many times while drawing a single quad and changing state often is bad for performance. Ideally you should collect all states that have the same state and batch render them (after setting up that state) if possible. Here (http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/glsl/) is a GLSL tutorial that should help you get started.